# AWS Cloudwatch log stream name not recognised

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

So,

I'm using the automated logging from AWS Lambda. It generates log streams with names that look like this: `2016/05/18/[$LATEST]99577d10a8cb420cb124a90c20d5653a`

I can query, using 'aws logs describe-log-streams', the available log streams and get some JSON containing these names alongside other meta data.

However if I then try to do this:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/categorise --log-stream-name "2016/05/18/[$LATEST]99577d10a8cb420cb124a90c20d5653a"
```

I get an error

```
A client error (ResourceNotFoundException) occurred when calling the GetLogEvents operation: The specified log stream does not exist.
```

So if the log stream name returned by the describe log streams command doesn't actually exist. What is it?

I've tried hacking around with the command a bit, removing the `[$LATEST]`, quoting it, escaping it. But no joy. Has anyone managed to retrieve their Lambda log events using the aws cli?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Immediately after posting this I figured it out... The `$` in `[$LATEST]` needs to be escaped... So it should look something like `[\$LATEST]`.

Comment: This is SO useful. Thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: Or use single quotes instead of double quotes, then your shell won't interpolate $LATEST as a shell variable.

Comment: This is very useful, you've saved me so muuuch time. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @aychedee for the descriptive write up, your description ranks highly in search and saved me a lot of time!